# Mapping data from other dataset. Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, mapping, multiple-columns

So i got 2 datasets, `df1` has the colour for all fruits and `df2` don't. How do I map the color values for `df2` based on the color data from `d1`, according to the fruit names?

```
               df1                                  df2
Name               Color             Name              Color
Apple              Red               Orange            Na
Orange             Orange            Coconut           Na
Pear               Pear              Pear              Na
Pear               Pear              Strawberries      Na
Papaya             Papaya            Banana            Na
Watermelon         Watermelon        Papaya            Na
               "                  "                 "                 "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), but first need [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df2['Color'] = df2['Name'].map(df1.set_index('Name')['Color'].drop_duplicates())
print (df2)
           Name   Color
0        Orange  Orange
1       Coconut     NaN
2          Pear    Pear
3  Strawberries     NaN
4        Banana     NaN
5        Papaya  Papaya
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2.drop('Color', axis=1),df1.drop_duplicates(), how='left')
print (df2)
           Name   Color
0        Orange  Orange
1       Coconut     NaN
2          Pear    Pear
3  Strawberries     NaN
4        Banana     NaN
5        Papaya  Papaya
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it gave me an error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: This does not scale well

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol - I think now answer is a bit different.

Comment: Not sure if i can use the join method as the sequence of both fruit names are different.

Comment: @JasonChingYuk this only works when specifying the 'name' column as 'on'.

Comment: It depends of number of columns. If DataFrames have only 2 columns, parameter `on` can be omited.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on="Name", how="left", suffixes=('_1','_2'))
```

if name is your index column you can just do a [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2 = df2.join(df1[['color']])
```

For a more complete example you can look at the answer above/below that was kind enough to elaborate on my answer.